# Passing values to Jenkins from Java

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Is there any way to pass value from `Java` (maven project) code to `Jenkins` job?.

Suppose that my java code looks like below.

```
public void generateRandom(){
    double random = Math.random();
    return random;
}
```

One of my Jenkins job in the pipeline will execute above code and the value returned by the code needs to be passed to a downstream job. The downstream job is parameterized.

Is it possible to pass the generated random number to the downstream job somehow like this -

```
${random}
```

Comment: How do you run your job?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov This job is triggered by another job. Within this job I am planning to compile and run the Java code and retrieve the value from it

Comment: "Compile and run"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @stackoverflow, you can pass the value as an input parameter of the job. If that's not enough, you should describe what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JFMeier   The Jenkins job will fetch my java code from repo, compile and execute. Then the value returned by the Java code needs to be passed to downstream Job

Comment: I think your best chance would be writing to an environment variable, e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("export MYVAR = " + someValue)` (assuming your jenkins is running in a linux environment). This may be dirty, but I'm not aware of a better option...

Comment: I just wonder: You seem to be writing "pipeline stuff" in Java, and want to compile and execute in in Jenkins. Why not write your logic in Groovy and execute it directly through Jenkins?

Comment: @JFMeier the above code snippet is just an example. The real project is coded in Java and the value to be returned is obtained after some complex calculation. So rewriting in Groovy is a overhead

Comment: you can easily import Java libraries through Grape in Groovy. Compiling and running Java code during a pipeline seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a property read operation said like here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text.

May be you can write the output of java code to some file, and make that input for the next jenkins job.?